# Given y(x), find indicial equation of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, roots

So I want to find the indicial equation of this ODE:

$$xy''+y'-y=0$$

I'm told that:

$y(x)=x^r(1+\sum_{m=1}^\infty a_mx^m)$ and that $r=0$ is the only solution of the indicial equation.

I've practiced finding indicial equations and can usually do them but I'm finding this $y(x)$ difficult to use. I'm not entirely sure what my $y'(x)$ and $y''(x)$ would look like here, I've tried a couple ways of differentiating $y(x)$ but I don't get anything I can use.

If anyone could help out and show me how I would obtain my $y''(x)$ and $y'(x)$ it would really help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just follow the example of the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method), or [look at the solution given on this site already](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1579870/second-solution-of-ode-xyy-y-0?rq=1).

Comment: Both these examples are similar to mine and the second link is what I would be doing to find the indicial equation but I can't set my $y(x)$ to anything, I'm told to assume that my $y(x)$ equals what is given. In both these examples we have a bit more freedom, that's my issue with this question, I'm being forced to use that specific $y(x)$ and differentiating it is confusing and painful, that's why I'm struggling to get the answer

Comment: They're definitely both useful examples though, they just don't really solve my issue in this case